# convert byte stream to string from socket in server side java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, inputstream

I serialized an object to bytes and send to the server side.
in the server side i got the byte stream but i want to print the object/string i got from the server in order to verify i got it well

server side:

```
    CarServerSocket = new ServerSocket(4441);
    System.out.println("Server is ready and waiting for connection from client..\n");
    try {
        while (true) {
            carSocket = CarServerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Server Connected");         
            final DataInputStream bytesIR  = new DataInputStream(carSocket.getInputStream());
            bytesIRLength = bytesIR.readInt();  
                while (bytesIRLength > 0) { 
                    byte[] messageIn = new byte[bytesIRLength];
                    bytesIR.readFully(messageIn,0,messageIn.length);
                    bytesIR.readUTF();

                }
            }
    }catch(EOFException e ){
            System.out.println("\ngot all objects from client.\ndisconnecting server...");              
            CarServerSocket.close();
            carSocket.close();
        }
    }
```

Cliend side - serialization

```
objectOut.writeObject(CarList[i]); // converting object to bytes.
        objectOut.flush();
        objectInBytes = byteOut.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("Sending car object #"+i);
        dOut.writeInt(objectInBytes.length); // getting object bytes size.
        dOut.write(objectInBytes); // sending object in bytes.
```

I tired to use: toString(), readUTF()... but no luck.

can anyone please advise how i solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: You might actually want to use an `ObjectInputStream` & the `readObject()` method.  Of course, then you'd want to be writing to an `ObjectOutputStream` ...

Comment: How about using 'new String(messageIn)'?

Comment: If you want meaningful help you need to show us the client side code where the object is serialized.

Comment: i can't use ObjectOutputStream since i must use (messageIn,0,messageIn.length) in the server side. means read a byte stream and extract the object from it

Comment: The answer to the question still depends on how the data was sent. Was it (a) `writeUTF()` (b) a line (c) other, and if so what? Your comment about not using `ObjectOutputStream` flatly contradicts your statement that you serialized the object. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read data from your InputStream with some kind of InputStreamReader, something like this :

```
    CarServerSocket = new ServerSocket(4441);
    System.out.println("Server is ready and waiting for connection from client..\n");
    try {
        while (true) {
            carSocket = CarServerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Server Connected"); 
            StringBuilder yourData = new StringBuilder();
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(carSocket.getInputStream()))
                .lines().forEach(stringBuilder::append);
            System.out.println(yourData.toString());
    }catch(EOFException e ){
            System.out.println("\ngot all objects from client.\ndisconnecting server...");              
            CarServerSocket.close();
            carSocket.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ObjectInputStream` to deserialize objects.  Ok, so your object is entirely contained in a datagram that you've already received.  You just need to turn the data buffer into an `ObjectInputStream`.  Coding from the hip, this would be something like ...

```
try( ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(messageIn);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais)) {
    Object o = ois.readObject();
}
```

---

***Edit***: Here is some complete code showing this working.

```
public class ByteStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Server server = new Server(4441);
        new Thread(server).start();

        Client client = new Client(4441);
        new Thread(client).start();
    }
}

class Client implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;

    Client(int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyObject send = new MyObject();
        send.x = 10;
        send.msg = "X = ";

        try {
            try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {

                oos.writeObject(send);
                oos.flush();
                byte[] objectInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                int length = objectInBytes.length;
                System.out.println("Client: sending 'objectInBytes' length = " + length);
                dos.writeInt(length);
                dos.write(objectInBytes);
            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Server implements Runnable {
    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    DataInputStream bytesIR = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                int length = bytesIR.readInt();
                byte[] messageIn = new byte[length];
                bytesIR.readFully(messageIn);
                System.out.println("Server: got datagram length = " + length);
                process(messageIn);
            } finally {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void process(byte[] messageIn) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(messageIn);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais)) {
            Object o = ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(o.getClass() + ": " + o);
        }
    }
}

class MyObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1478875967217194114L;
    double x;
    String msg;
    public String toString() { return msg + x; }
}
```

And the output:

```
Client: sending 'objectInBytes' length = 75
Server: got datagram length = 75
class MyObject: X = 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objectOut.writeObject(CarList[i]); // converting object to bytes.
objectOut.flush();
objectInBytes = byteOut.toByteArray();
System.out.println("Sending car object #"+i);
dOut.writeInt(objectInBytes.length); // getting object bytes size.
dOut.write(objectInBytes); // sending object in bytes.
```

All this is completely pointless. It just wastes time and space. Just use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` directly to the socket at the sender, and `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` directly from the socket at the receiver.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the use is, there is never any point in writing redundant code. If someone has really specified that bizarre sending technique they need to be asked why.